# I need to change the date format in power apps

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

i am trying to built an app in powerapps which will send an event in outlook calendar. i have create a flow i test it and works fine but i have to insert the date in "yyyy/mm/dd" format. when i try to add the flow in powerapps, the powerapps send the date in "dd/mm/yyyy" format and the flow doesn't recognize it as a date and doesn't send the event in calendar. i have insert this on the button action...

```
Προσθήκηστοημερολόγιο.Run(DateTimeValue(DateValue1.SelectedDate & " " & HourValue1.SelectedText.Value  & ":" & MinuteValue1.SelectedText.Value) & DateTimeFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:")
```

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Arguments from Power Apps to flows are always of type strings, so you don't need the DateTimeValue (which converts *from* strings to date/time). You need the Text function, which allows you to format a date/time value in a specific way, something like the expression below:

```
Προσθήκηστοημερολόγιο.Run(
    Text(DateValue1.SelectedDate, "yyyy/mm/dd") & " " &
    Text(
        Time(HourValue1.SelectedText.Value, MinuteValue1.SelectedText.Value, 0),
        "hh:mm:ss"))
```

If the types of [HourValue1 | MinuteValue1].SelectedText.Value is not a number (i.e., they are strings), then you may be able to concatenate them directly instead of using the Text and Time functions:

```
Προσθήκηστοημερολόγιο.Run(
    Text(DateValue1.SelectedDate, "yyyy/mm/dd") & " " &
    HourValue1.SelectedText.Value & ":" & MinuteValue1.SelectedText.Value & ":00")
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, i tried the first example but the powerapps doesn't accept the comma before the "yyyy/mm/dd"...

Comment: Depending on your environment, you may need to use `;` to separate the parameters to the functions - take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/global-apps#authoring-environment for more details.

Comment: thanks again, yes you were right, but still nothing is added in the calendar. i would like to tell that i don't insert the date and time as a text but from calendar and time select...

Answer (score 0):

at the end i created an automatic flow to create the event when an item is being added in the sharepoint list and works fine.
thank you!